# How to model mixtures with two inputs using differential equations?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question:

> A river flows into a lake initially containing $100\ \mathrm{km}^3$ of pure water at a rate of $48\ \mathrm{km}^3/\text{year}$. Pollutant from a factor is also released into the lake at $2\ \mathrm{km}^3/\text{year}$. Assume that the pollutant mixes immediately and uniformly. The lake flows into another river at $40\ \mathrm{km}^3/\text{year}$.
>
> Find $x(t)\ \mathrm{km}^3$ as the amount of pollutant in the lake after t years.

To my understanding, we can model $\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt} = \text{rate in} - \text{rate out}$.

$\text{rate in}$ can be calculated as $\text{concentration in}\times\text{rate in}$.
Thus rate in would be: $\dfrac2{50}\times50=2$

However I am not sure how to model rate out, would it be:
$\dfrac x{100}\times40$?

The solution is:
$$\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt} + \frac{4x}{10+t}=2$$

Comment: what is the quantity of pollutant in the factory water?

Comment: @qbert it doesn't say so I'm assuming it's pure pollutant? I think I have a solution.

The flow rate is 40 and the concentration out would be x/(100+10t) because the rate out is lower than the rate in meaning volume will increase with time. When we multiply these we can simply to 4x/(10+t), thus giving us the solution!